# matlab C++ mex file handling exceptions

Tags: c++, matlab, exception, mex, abi

Using older compilers (`gcc 4.1` in Red Hat 5) I was able to safely throw and  catch exceptions inside the C++ code that was buried inside the `mexFunction` function calls (the `mexFunction` itself is C code).

With a newer version of the compiler (`gcc 4.9`), most of the times everything works fine, but if an exception is thrown, matlab crashes. We're still using an old version (R2008a) of matlab.

Digging deep down, I see with a debugger (and believe me, debugging matlab mex files is a pain) that the problem seems to be incompatibility between the C++ exceptions the compiler is throwing, and the `libstdc++` that matlab ships with.

If I try to use the system `libstdc++` instead, matlab crashes from the beginning, it really needs its own private (old?) library.

Is there any way of figuring out for a particular `libstdc++` what exception ABI it uses?

Can I specify any flags to the compiler to use an older version of the exception ABI?

Or can I write the exceptions in a way that they use a more conservative throw/catch approach that all libstdc++ versions can handle?

It would be really a pain to have to create multiple mex files with different compilers that match the different versions of matlab. And even more pain to get rid of exceptions. What is the point of writing C++ without exceptions?

In terms of ABI everything else seems to be working quite well, as long as an exception is not thrown. The same code has been exhaustively tested with exceptions outside matlab (not called from mexFunction, but from main) and works fine, it is definitively not the case that a particular exception is not being caught.

Comment: Well, but *C* has no exceptions... it shouldn´t / hasn´t to work across a C interface in the first place.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You're not letting the exceptions ride all the way back to MATLAB, are you?  I've never had a problem with exception handing inside the `mexFunction`.  Also, in Linux can you change the runtime linkage between static and dynamic?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding about C. The mexFunction() called from MATLAB is actually C code, which calls another function foo() that is written in C++. foo() catches all the exceptions inside, so there is no danger of them riding all the way back to MATLAB. The same test works fine with an old 4.1 C++ compiler in Red Hat 5, even throwing exceptions (inside foo()). But fails when I try to port to 4.9 and Red Hat 6. I can try to post a small example that exhibit the behavior. Let me work on that. I was told it is very dangerous to statically link C++ code, could try to statically link mex.

Comment: Sort of resolved.  I tried to make a small example that would show how the failure occur. I was not successful. Then I chase after multiple leads ... exceptions NEED to export typeinfo information symbols, then I debugged in matlab to the point where it catches the exceptions but then got murky and eventually called terminate... Played I guess with a thousand variants of symbol visibility, etc. according to some suggestion here or there. Eventually the only thing that works - would love to know why - is compiling the library that has the exception class defined with -O1 instead of -O3.